# Rails Models - Can they have helpers? that allow for rendering a view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In a rails 3 model. can I use a helper? If so how. And in that helper can I render a view allowing me to store the view in the db?

Thanks

Comment: You want to store your views inside a database? Actually storing the ERB might be a bad idea, but I could see the use in storing something like Markdown.

Answer (score 0):

If storing your views in the DB is what you are after you shouldn't have to edit the model. You can use some code like:

```
render :inline => erb.view
```

erb is the view record and erb.view is the actual erb text.

Comment: thanks but I'm not following this? what is the view here and where do you pass params?

Comment: Also, is that then getting rendered as a view? The partial I want to render in the model has a param I need to pass. thanks

Comment: You want to store views in the db correct? You can do this by calling `render :inline => view_code` where you get this code for the view is up to you. You would call this from the controller to render your view.

Comment: Why would you render anything in the model? You dont render in the model.

Comment: Thanks but that won't work. I want to store the output of the view after it's been processed. And I want that to be possible in the model as an observer triggers the action.

Comment: I need to store the results of the render in the model. Is there a way to call the controller from the model to get the output?

Comment: You can include the view helpers by using `include ActionController::Base` and you can render a view by calling `render_to_string` http://rails.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html#M000465

Comment: If I add that include to the model I get the error 'TypeError (wrong argument type Class (expected Module)):'

Comment: try `include ActionController::Helpers`

Comment: New error 'NoMethodError (undefined method `config_accessor' for #<Class:0x10353e360>):
'

Comment: I did the following in the model, ActionController::Base.new.send(:render_to_string,
                                      :partial => 'wall_feeds/feed_item',
                                      :locals => {:feed_item => self})

Comment: Also added 'include ActionController::Helpers' at the top of the model, but that errors w the config_accessor error mentioned above.

Comment: And this is why this is a bad idea... You should just use rails built in caching system with memcached. If you really want to save generated views do it in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it would help if you told us **why?** Why do you want to store a view's raw text in the db?

> "output of the view after it's been
>   processed."
>   I need to store the results of the
>   render in the model. Is there a way to
>   call the controller from the model to
>   get the output?

Are you wanting to render custom or dynamic views based on a model? Why does this view need to be tied so closely to the model? Surely if you're wanting to store some kind of raw html/ruby in the db then you're going to try and get it back out again later down the road. Have you considered taking another route altogether?

"Is there a way to call the controller from the model to get the output?" Really this is the part that makes it seem like you aren't quite looking at it 'the rails way', but perhaps if we knew more about why and what you're trying to do, we can tell you if there even **is** a rails way. (I say this because with the MVC design convention used by rails, models don't render views, controllers do. There is a good reason for the abstraction/separation.)

Helper-style Model processing can be done with [Observers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#observers) that hook in to :before_create/:after_create style callbacks during the ActiveRecord DB storing process.